# Max function for complex matrix in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to compare matrices with element by element and find the maximum values of the matrices, like I have three 3x3 matrices

```
tdata = {{{1, 5, 1}, {7, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 3}}, {{2, 0, 8}, {9, 8, 2}, {2,
 3, 0}}, {{2, 2, 9}, {10, 9, 5}, {9, 3, 3}}}
```

Then by using

```
MapThread[Max, tdata, 2] // MatrixForm
```

I can get the correct result.

```
{{2, 5, 9}, {10, 9, 5}, {9, 4, 3}}
```

However, when the matrices are complex matrices, Max function doesn't work. For example,

```
tdata = {{{0.323031 + 5.23687 I, 8.92856 + 1.31365 I},
{9.94387 + 3.04104 I, 8.72483 + 2.5648 I}},
{{5.96575 + 9.2521 I,  8.58461 + 2.56753 I},
{0.902715 + 3.75791 I, 4.06809 + 8.61552 I}},
{{9.36592 + 1.17263 I, 9.74628 + 2.22183 I},
{4.61866 + 4.61158 I, 9.0791 + 2.50036 I}}}
```

I have tried to implement a new Max function for complex matrices, but it doesn't work. Here is a demo,

```
complexMax[lis_] := Module[{abs = Abs[lis]}, Take[lis, Position[abs, Max[abs]][[1]]]]
```

Then

```
MapThread[complexMax, tdata, 2]
```

The result is like

```
{{complexMax[0.323031 + 5.23687 I, 5.96575 + 9.2521 I, 9.36592 + 1.17263 I], 
 complexMax[8.92856 + 1.31365 I, 8.58461 + 2.56753 I, 9.74628 + 2.22183 I]}, 
{complexMax[9.94387 + 3.04104 I, 0.902715 + 3.75791 I, 4.61866 + 4.61158 I], 
 complexMax[8.72483 + 2.5648 I, 4.06809 + 8.61552 I, 9.0791 + 2.50036 I]}}
```

Is there any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: I forgot to add a criteria for comparison. Usually, the absolute value is used to compare complex numbers. I have tried to implement the new comparison function but failed.

Comment: The post has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
MapThread[Last@SortBy[{##}, Abs] &, tdata, 2] // MatrixForm
```

(*  {{5.96575 + 9.2521 I, 9.74628 + 2.22183 I}, {9.94387 + 3.04104 I, 
  4.06809 + 8.61552 I}} *)

FWIW this sorts complex numbers by cannonical order, ( real part first )

```
MapThread[Last@Sort[{##}] &, tdata, 2] // MatrixForm
```

(* {{9.36592 + 1.17263 I, 9.74628 + 2.22183 I}, {9.94387 + 3.04104 I, 
  9.0791 + 2.50036 I}} *)

Note your approach works as well if you do this:

```
 MapThread[complexMax[{##}] &, tdata, 2]
```

The trick is the argument passed by `Mapthread` to your function is a sequence, not a list.

Comment: Great. How to wrap a sequence to a list bothers me a lot. `complexMax[{##}] &` is an elegant way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your current code is that using `MapThread` results in `complexMax` being called not with a single argument that is a list (i.e. `complexMax[{elem1, elem2, elem3...}]`), but with multiple arguments (i.e. `complexMax[elem1, elem2, elem3]`).

You can correct for this by declaring the argument not as a single expression (`lis_` w/ single underscore) but as a sequence of expressions: `lis__` with double underscore.

Making this correction leads to another issue, though - `Abs` expects a list as input, as does `Take`.  So you need to wrap `lis` in brackets in a couple places.

Lastly, looks like you need one additional `[[1]]` at the end.

```
complexMax[lis__] := Module[{abs = Abs[{lis}]},
  Take[{lis}, Position[abs, Max[abs]][[1]]][[1]]] 

MapThread[complexMax, tdata, 2]
```

Result

```
{{5.96575 + 9.2521 I, 9.74628 + 2.22183 I}, {9.94387 + 3.04104 I, 
  4.06809 + 8.61552 I}}
```

Comment: The third argument to `MapThread` is the integer level, different from `Map` which takes a levelspec..

Comment: Yes, I had accidentally switched to using `Map` and got confused.  My edit goes back to `MapThread`

Comment: That's it. I noticed that the argument passed to `complexMax` is a sequence and tried to wrap it in the body. However, it doesn't work. The reason is the underscore, i.e., `lis__` instead of `lis_`. Thank you for your comment, latkin.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated StackExchange site for *Mathematica* now: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ -- please ask your future questions there.

---

As already explained by latkin your max function needs to accept multiple arguments if it is to be used as shown in `MapThread`.  You can write the function to handle both forms by using a second pattern, e.g. `cMax[ns__] := cMax[{ns}]`.

Faster than `Position` is `Ordering`.

```
cMax[ns__] := cMax[{ns}]

cMax[lis_List] := lis ~Extract~ Ordering[Abs[lis], -1]
```

Now:

```
MapThread[cMax, tdata, 2]
```

> ```
> {{5.96575 + 9.2521 I, 9.74628 + 2.22183 I},
>  {9.94387 + 3.04104 I, 4.06809 + 8.61552 I}}
> ```

However, when working with packed data it will be faster *not* to use `MapThread`, which results in unpacking but rather to keep the numbers in lists by using `Transpose`:

```
Map[cMax, Transpose[tdata, {3, 1, 2}], {2}]
```

> ```
> {{5.96575 + 9.2521 I, 9.74628 + 2.22183 I},
>  {9.94387 + 3.04104 I, 4.06809 + 8.61552 I}}
> ```

Timings:

```
cd = RandomComplex[9 + 9 I, {15000, 7, 7}];

MapThread[Last@SortBy[{##}, Abs] &, cd, 2] // Timing // First

MapThread[cMax, cd, 2]                     // Timing // First

Map[cMax, Transpose[cd, {3, 1, 2}], {2}]   // Timing // First
```

> 0.562
>
> 0.483
>
> 0.0156

Comment: Amazing answer. It's really useful to know the performance issue. Thanks.